# Bash to rename multiple files to append different folder names

Tags: bash, loops, append, rename

I am currently analysing genomes from SPADESs.
I currently have 500+ directories from SPADES named EC18PR-0001, EC18PR-0002, ECPK-0001 ECPK-0002 etc. And inside each  directory is a contig file named 'contigs.fasta'.

I was trying to find a way to go through each directory and append each individual directory name to the 'contigs.fasta' file so it would be like: EC18PR-0001-contigs.fasta.

This loop doesn't seem to work:

```
for file in *EC18

do

sample=${file/.fasta} perl -ane 
'if(/\>/){$a++;print ">NODE_$a\n"}else{print;}' ${sample}.fasta >
/pathway/where/files/are/SPADEs/${sample}.fasta 

done
```

Comment: `for f in EC18* ; do test -f "$f/contigs.fasta" && mv "$f/contigs.fasta" "$f/$f-contigs.fasta" ; done`

Comment: If perl based `rename` command is available, try `rename 's#(.*?)/(.*)#$1/$1-$2#' EC18*/contigs.fasta`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
for file in EC18*/*; do
    if [[ $file =~ contigs.fasta ]];then
        echo $(echo $file | sed 's#/#-#g')
    fi
done
```